# Laravel Multiple auth error with condition

Tags: php, laravel

i need to specify redirection depent on which user is authentified. I add a column in the default laravel users table : "is_admin" with values "1" and "0"

In my controller i tried :

```
 if(Auth::user()->is_admin=1){
  return view('index');
 }
 else {
 return view('auth.login'); 
  };
```

But seem's my condition always true even if the auth has is_admin =0

How can i solve that problem ? Is there a better way to do this condition ? thanks

Comment: what is "is_admin" ?

Comment: a new column i added in the table users

Comment: what is the type of the column in which you save the `is_admin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're assigning a value in your `if` statement, you've got a single `=` which assigns a value, rather than a double `==` (or triple `===`) to compare values.

What's happening when you've only got a single `=` is that you're assigning the value `1` to whatever is before the `=` and that will evaluate to a "truthy" value meaning that the `if` will always be true no matter what and the `else` will never execute.

You should change it to this:

```
if (Auth::user()->is_admin == 1){ // Notice the two == here
    return view('index');
} else {
    return view('auth.login'); 
}
```

Notice that I have removed the semicolon at the end, it isn't necessary.

Comment: In order to avoid mistakes like this in the future, you should utilize Attributes. In your User model, create an attribute called "getIsAdminAttribute" and let it return true or false. Then you would just reference it like this: if(Auth::user()->isAdmin). By doing it this way, you eliminate the potential error of assigning values when you meant to evaluate.

Comment: Or can keep constants on the left side of check. Like `if (1 == Auth::user()->is_admin) {/**/}` or `if (true == $unknownState) {/**/}` If ever there is forgotten one equal sign and stays only one equal sign between, it will throw an error. +1 for spotting error.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this kind of issue you kind manage the way you specify value by creating `const` in you `User` Model. this allow you to have the same values which have same type all the time

```
class User extends Model
{
    const ADMIN_USER = "1";
    const REGULAR_USER = "0";

    public function is_admin()
    {
        return $this->attributes['is_admin'] == self::ADMIN_USER;
    }
}
```

when creating a non admin user you use this

```
User::create([
    // SET OTHER ATTRIBUTE
    'is_admin' => User::REGULAR_USER
]);
```

when creating the admin user you use this

```
User::create([
    // SET OTHER ATTRIBUTE
    'is_admin' => User::ADMIN_USER
]);
```

And when it come to check it in your view, you will have just to call the `is_admin` method on the `Auth::user()->is_admin()`

```
if(Auth::user()->is_admin()){
    // Your code goes here
} else {
    // And other codes goes here
}
```